# Rearranging matrix using col2im in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

My matrix is this:

```
 0     3     0
 0     1     2
 4     4     1
```

I use `im2col` on it like this:

```
 im2col(A, [2 2], 'sliding')
```

which correctly yields this:

```
 0     0     3     1
 0     4     1     4
 3     1     0     2
 1     4     2     1
```

I call this matrix `K`. Now I use `col2im` to go back to my original matrix. From the Matlab documentation I use this:

```
col2im(K, [2 2], [5 5],'sliding')
```

But this doesn't gives me my original matrix `A`. Reason being `[5 5]` should be `[4 4]` to get a 3*3 matrix for starters. But when I do that I get

```
??? Error using ==> reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.
```

Why is that? And how can I get my original matrix back?

Answer (score 0):

Fromthe docs:

> A = col2im(B,[m n],[mm nn],'sliding') rearranges the row vector B into
>   a matrix of size (mm-m+1)-by-(nn-n+1). B must be a vector of size
>   1-by-(mm-m+1)*(nn-n+1). B is usually the result of processing the
>   output of im2col(...,'sliding') using a column compression function
>   (such as sum).

So that says to me you should be trying something like:

```
col2im(sum(K), [2 2], [4 4],'sliding')
```

however that would require `K` to have 9 columns. I don't have the image processing toolbox handy to test this right now

Answer (score 0):

Your `col2im` doesn't work because it uses `reshape` and for that the number of elements of the matrix you wish to reshape (K) and the new one, need to be the same. This is not the case anymore, as through your transformation of A with `im2col` you obviously changed that. A has 9 and K 16 elements.

So you basically need to get back to a 3*3 matrix again by getting rid of the redundand doubled elements (due to the overlapping 2*2 blocks used in `im2col`) in K.
For that you could just make a new matrix (C) with the elements that you need:

```
C = [K([1,3,11;2,4,12;6,8,16])]
```

As long as you first went from a 3*3 to a 4*4 matrix using the same order of blocks this should work.

Maybe you could tell us more about what you really want to achieve, because I don't see any reason for this in the first place. It may also be possible that you might be better off using other functions instead, but I can only see that if I know what the reasoning behind your question is.

Answer (score 0):

```
clear
clc
img = double(imread('tire.tif'));
[r c] = size(img);
w = 8;
imgBlock = im2col(img,[w w],'sliding'); imgBlock = imgBlock(:);
[x y] = meshgrid(1:c,1:r);
xx = im2col(x,[w w], 'sliding'); xx = xx(:);
yy = im2col(y,[w w], 'sliding'); yy = yy(:);
img2 = accumarray([yy xx], imgBlock, [], @mean);
figure,imshow(img, []);
figure,imshow(img2,[]);
```

% random matrix as image

img = randi(10,4)

img =

```
 6     2     2     7
 5     8     7     8
 1     4     3     5
 4     6     7     1
```

% matrix size

[r c] = size(img)

% patch size

w = 2;

% image to patch

imgBlock = im2col(img,[w w],'sliding')

% image patchs matrix to a vector

imgBlock = imgBlock(:);

r =

```
 4
```

c =

```
 4
```

imgBlock =

```
 6     5     1     2     8     4     2     7     3
 5     1     4     8     4     6     7     3     7
 2     8     4     2     7     3     7     8     5
 8     4     6     7     3     7     8     5     1
```

% index matrix size equal image size

[x y] = meshgrid(1:c,1:r)

% index matric to patchs;to vector

xx = im2col(x,[w w], 'sliding'); xx = xx(:);

yy = im2col(y,[w w], 'sliding'); yy = yy(:);

x =

```
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     3     4
```

y =

```
 1     1     1     1
 2     2     2     2
 3     3     3     3
 4     4     4     4
```

% yy :row index   xx: column index

% applies the function mean to each subset of elements in imgBlock that have identical subscripts in [yy xx].

img2 = accumarray([yy xx], imgBlock, [], @mean);

img

img2

img =

```
 6     2     2     7
 5     8     7     8
 1     4     3     5
 4     6     7     1
```

img2 =

```
 6     2     2     7
 5     8     7     8
 1     4     3     5
 4     6     7     1
```

%  [col,row,value]

a = [xx,yy,imgBlock]

a =

```
 1     1     6
 1     2     5
 2     1     2
 2     2     8
 1     2     5
 1     3     1
 2     2     8
 2     3     4
 1     3     1
 1     4     4
 2     3     4
 2     4     6
 2     1     2
 2     2     8
 3     1     2
 3     2     7
 2     2     8
 2     3     4
 3     2     7
 3     3     3
 2     3     4
 2     4     6
 3     3     3
 3     4     7
 3     1     2
 3     2     7
 4     1     7
 4     2     8
 3     2     7
 3     3     3
 4     2     8
 4     3     5
 3     3     3
 3     4     7
 4     3     5
 4     4     1
```

% The number of times that img(2,2) occurs in the matrix img

a(xx == 2 & yy == 2,:)

ans =

```
 2     2     8
 2     2     8
 2     2     8
 2     2     8
```

Comment: Maybe can you explain your answer a bit? Also is `clear` and `clc` really needed?

Comment: @Daitu An answer on SO should contain some kind of explanation, not just code thrown in the answer.